# how to use surveyjs with react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, surveyjs

Are there any code samples that show how to use Surveyjs with React and TypeScript?  I tried importing it into my project and using the sample code from here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/surveyjs-react-stackoverflow45544026

I got a module parse error on this line.

```
import "survey-react/survey.css";
```

So, I tried commenting it out to see what would happen.  Then, TypeScript complained about this line

```
var model = new Survey.Model(json);
```

It said Model does not exist.

My project contains the type definitions in survey.react.d.ts.  So, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Surveyjs in Angular which uses TypeScript.

I generally do : `import * as Survey from "survey-angular";` and we dont any errors like Model does not exist etc.

I would suggest you to try out: `import * as Survey from "survey-react";` and check if its working.

Also, if you want quick start boilerplate of React+Surveyjs , you clone/fork from this [link](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs_react_quickstart)